# Why ajax request fails?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to perform some calculations using the url shown in the below code , Everytime i run the code  alert() in error:functiom is being called . PLs help

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#form1").validationEngine();
    if($('div input[type=text]').val() != "") {
        var textfield2=document.getElementById("textfield2").value;
        var textarea=document.getElementById("textarea").value;
        var dataS=$("#form1").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://some_site/ppp.php",
            data:dataS,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function( ){
                $("#result").empty().html("<h2>Your request has been received </h2>"); 
            },
            error: function(){                          
                alert(dataS);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: is the url you're making the request to on the same domain as the page that's making the request?

Comment: My guess is it's failing because it's a cross-domain request and the cross-domain server isn't implementing CORS.

Comment: @JohnBoker I don't think so, see `crossDomain: true`?

Comment: no .. its on a different domain

Comment: @user2286230: Well then, KevinB's comment is your answer... if you can work on the X-domain server, add CORS support... if not: have a rethink

Comment: If you can't get CORS enabled, then you may need to look at implementing a proxy at your end.  So your AJAX request goes to a local URL, which then on the server side (e.g. in PHP) makes the request to the other domain, and returns the response.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mess around with a cross-domain POST. I've found CORS to be notoriously difficult to get working reliably in all browsers. Some browsers will send the request but ignore the result, some will not even send the request, some will work fine.

Instead, consider using either a PHP proxy on the same domain, or use GET with JSONP to send the request instead.